# How do I add a message to browser.wait() without changing the default timeout?

Tags: angular, typescript, selenium, protractor

I have some code

```
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(elementName));
```

Often this fails and just says "expected true to be false".  This does my head in.  When it fails I want it to give me a more descriptive reason why it failed with the elementName.

So I want to change it to add in a message.  The browser.wait definition is:

```
wait(condition: WebElementCondition, opt_timeout?: number, opt_message?: string): WebElementPromise;
```

So I can do:

```
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element), 0, `Expected presence of ${elementName}`);
```

But I don't want to change the opt_timeout when I don't have to.  Is there any way to pass the opt_message without passing the opt_timeout?

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element), undefined, `Expected presence of ${elementName}`);
```

You can pass undefined in the second argument. Using undefined will not change the default timeout.

This works fine

[image]